# Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded when installing xlsx

Tags: r

Im trying to install the xlsx package. Installing works fine but when i load the library I get the following error:

```
> require(xlsx)
Loading required package: xlsx
Loading required package: rJava
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
 call: fun(libname, pkgname)
 error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-    installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
 In addition: Warning messages:
 1: package ‘xlsx’ was built under R version 3.2.3 
 2: package ‘rJava’ was built under R version 3.2.3 
Failed with error:  ‘package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded’
```

I googled around and say that installing the right version of Java might be the issue. However, when I downloaded the newest version and started a new r-session I still get the same issue.

Are there more people experiencing this issue? And some quick fix?

Comment: Did you boot after Java install?

Comment: Also upgrade your version of R.

Comment: Make sure you have the same java version as your r version. If you use 64 bit R, install 64 bit java

Comment: `openxlsx` does not require rJava (i think it uses c++) and works like a charm.

Comment: I witnessed this exact same issue the other day. Try unloading the packages, deleteing them and then reinstalling - possibly reinstalling `rJava` on its own. This worked for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Linux and when I update R or Java to use the rJava library (needed by xlsx) I need to run this commands form a shell (outside the R session)

```
sudo su -
R CMD javareconf
```

I hope this helps.